# Getting java classes from multiple wsdls

Tags: java, maven, wsdl

I have a Maven project where i need to generate java classes from multiple wsdl files.
I have analysed using maven plugins `axistools-maven-plugin` and `cxf-codegen-plugin` but the problem i am facing are is that Java files from different wsdl's should go to different packages.

I have checked this link : http://decimalsolutions.blogspot.in/2011/10/wsdl2java-maven2.html but it doesn't solve my problem.

How to achieve this?

Comment: do you have any idea how to configure dynamic WSDL in  <wsdlOption>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) states you can use the `<extraarg>` element to pass in parameters to the [wdsl to java process](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). So, you can configure your `cxf-codegen-plugin` in the following manner

```
<configuration>
    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-code/mywebservice</sourceRoot>
    <wsdlOptions>
        <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/serviceOne.wsdl</wsdl>
            <extraargs>
                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                <extraarg>first.packagename</extraarg>
            </extraargs>
        </wsdlOption>
        <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/serviceTwo.wsdl</wsdl>
                <extraargs>
                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                <extraarg>another.packagename</extraarg>
            </extraargs>
        </wsdlOption>
    </wsdlOptions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a jaxb binding file, you can change the package (see [this](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Customizing_Java_packages.html) documentation).

If you're using maven and the cxf plugin, you can add this to your pom.xml:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl><path_to_wsdl</wsdl>
                                <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                                <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at XJC bindings, there are some notes on the [Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) and  if you are happy with the CXF plugin you can pass a separate bindings file for each WSDL using the code you can see in example one on the [plugin's site](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).

An example fragment from  the plugin configuration:

```
...
<configuration>
   <wsdlOptions>
      <wsdlOption>
          <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/first.wsdl</wsdl>
          <bindingFiles>
              <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/first.xjb</bindingFile>
          </bindingFiles>
      </wsdlOption>
      <wsdlOption>
          <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/second.wsdl</wsdl>
          <bindingFiles>
              <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/second.xjb</bindingFile>
          </bindingFiles>
      </wsdlOption>
   </wsdlOptions>
</configuration>
...
```

Where first.xjb would contain:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="path/to//serviceOne.wsdl"
      xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        ...
    </jxb:globalBindings>

    <jxb:schemaBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
        <jxb:package name="your.first.package"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Now you can configure all manner of translations and mappings.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but not keen on adding an additional file

Comment: TBH if you are only interested in the package name then this is probably overkill. When you start needing more complex type mappings, class name mappings and other customisations, remember this!